# Excel count by columns

Tags: excel, sorting, count

I am trying to count all of the contents of two columns and then arrange the data in the follow way. I want to gather and list all names in both columns A and C, consolidate them all in column E while sorting them by their successful %.  I have tried for a bit and could not figure out which function this would do this.

[image]

Comment: You should look into using pivot tables.  You _could_ try to do this using native Excel functions, but it would be a headache and also error prone.

Comment: Yup, my thought exactly, I'd try the pivot way. Failing that, if you want an alternative you can doe this relatively easyily by using a couple of dictionanaries, and aggregating these by hand. I would at least try the pivot first...

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this formula into cell F2:
    =COUNTIF($A$2:$A$15,$E2)

You can then copy it down into cells F3 and below.

Adjust the reference range $A2:$A15 to column C for the unsuccessful count.